# template types in std is_member_function_pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am referring to a possible implementation of `std::is_member_function_pointer` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper : std::false_type {};

template< class T, class U>
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper<T U::*> : std::is_function<T> {};

template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer : is_member_function_pointer_helper< std::remove_cv_t<T> >     


#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    void member() { }
};



int main()
{
    // fails at compile time if A::member is a data member and not a function
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&A::member)>::value,
                  "A::member is not a member function."); 
}
```

I know that

> "dectype(&A::member)"

will be

> "void (A::*)()"

But I dont understand what type T and type U map to in "void (A::*)()"?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern `void (A::*)()` decomposes into `T U::*` where `U` is `A` and `T` is `void ()`.
You can see the construction in inverse, like this:

```
struct A {};

using T = void ();
using U = A;

template <typename> struct print;

int main() {
    print<T U::*>{};
    // error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'print<void (A::*)()>'
}
```

So the `T` as `void ()` is passed to `std::is_function` which determines whether the given type is a function type.

In the case of pointer to data members, this fails because the deduced `T` is going to be a non-function type.

Answer (score 4):

```
template< class T, class U>
struct is_member_function_pointer_helper<T U::*> : std::is_function<T> {};
```

The above specialization will be a match if it were possible to decompose the the primary template argument into a *class type* `U` and a non-static *member type* `T`. The *class type* `U` is no longer useful here, because we've confirmed, its really a class.

The non-static *member-type* `T` is then passed as the template argument to `std::is_function` which has a whole lot of machinery in determining that `T` is indeed a function.

---

> But I dont understand what type `T` and type `U` map to in `void
>   (A::*)()`?

As explained above, once we are able to decompose `void (A::*)()` to match `T U::*` You will find out that `A::*` maps to `U::*`. Lets remove that pattern, we are left with `void ()` which is what `T` will be.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to understand if we first translate the type-id into English. That is, `void (A::*)()` is translated to "pointer to member of class `A` of type function of () returning `void`" and `T U::*` to "pointer to member of class `U` of type `T`". Now if we compare the two type we can see `U` corresponds to the class `A` and `T` corresponds to "function of () returning `void`", i.e. `void()`.